# .NET / Windows forms listview checkboxes rendering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, checkbox

I wonder why when using windows forms listview checkboxes the rendering is different according to if I use the Windows aero theme, but standard checkboxes stay with 3D rendering.

See this example without Windows aero theme.

A normal checkbox:

[image]

A listview with checkboxes:

[image]

How can I change the listview checkboxes style to get the same rendering than the normal checkbox ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With a Windows aero theme, listview checkboxes display correctly. The rendering issue occurs only if Windows aero theme is not enabled. I effectively use ListView.CheckBoxes = true.

Comment: I miss that *no aero theme* part, sorry. But then the answer is really easy: in classic mode there is [no visual styles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5141282/1997232) anymore. Winforms is inferior technology (wpf is not), `ListViewItem` is not `CheckBox`, instead `ListView` will draw **state** as something what only looks like checkbox. Without themes it looks that ugly. Try to [draw custom items in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20012097/1997232) in that mode. I think the problem is in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7ew2xw1(v=vs.110).aspx) method used by `ListView`.